# What happens with the Fock state after the Schwinger boson transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum

Let us imagine that initially, I had the following Hamiltonian.
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\alpha}{4} (a^\dagger b - b^\dagger a )^2 + \frac{\beta}{2}(a^\dagger a -  b^\dagger b), \quad [a,a^\dagger] = 1, \quad [b, b^\dagger] = 1,
$$
here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ - some real constants. And the initial state was $|\psi_0 \rangle = | n,0 \rangle  = \frac{(a^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|0,0\rangle $.

After applying Schwinger transformation ($L_z \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(a^\dagger a - b^\dagger b)$, $L_{+} \rightarrow a^\dagger b$, $L_{-} \rightarrow a b^\dagger$) the Hamiltonian transforms into
$$
\hat{H} = \alpha L_x^2 + \beta L_z,
$$
here $L_{x} = \frac{1}{2}\left( L_{+} + L_{-} \right)$.
What will be with the initial state under this transform?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an $i$ on $\beta$ to make the Hamiltonian hermitian? Also, the expression for $L_x$ doesn't follow the usual angular momentum conventions (and isn't hermitian either). I have instead $L_y=-\frac{i}{2}(L_+-L_-)$, so the second term in the hamiltonian should be $i\beta L_y$?

Comment: @qwyxivi Thank you! I made a mistake in the formula. So, now it should be ok.

Comment: The first hamiltonian has an integral of motion - the total number of quanta $N$ (eigenvalue of $a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b$). The Hamiltonian in terms of the momentum has one too - total angular momentum ($L^2 = N/2$). And the whole Hilbers space can be treated as a direct sum of Hilbert subspaces with different $N$. Probably, it can be used somehow.

Comment: no square on your $L_z$.... since you have not provided an initial state it’s hard to answer your question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks. I corrected the typo. The initial state is $|n, 0 \rangle$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're looking for the components of the state in the angular momentum representation? The state itself is technically the same, but you want it in a different basis.

We need to think about the actions of $L^2$ and $L_z$ in the Fock space. Consider

$$L_z(a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle = \frac{n}{2} (a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle$$

$L_z=\frac{1}{2}(N_a-N_b)$ is just two number operators, so this is easy to evaluate.

$L^2$ takes a bit of work; first, you should define $L_y=\frac{i}{2}(L_--L_+)$. Doing some operator math, you should get that

$$L^2 = L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2 = L_z^2-\frac{1}{4}(L_--L_+)^2+-\frac{1}{4}(L_-+L_+)^2 = L_z^2-\frac{1}{4}(2L_+L_-+2L_-L_+)
=\frac{1}{4}(a^\dagger aa^\dagger a+b^\dagger bb^\dagger b-2a^\dagger ab^\dagger b + 2a^\dagger ba b^\dagger+2a b^\dagger a^\dagger b )
=\frac{1}{4}(N_a^2+N_b^2+2N_aN_b+2N_a+2N_b )=\frac{1}{4}(N_a+N_b)(N_a+N_b+2)$$

In particular,

$$L^2(a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle = \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) (a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle$$

This is really nice, since this tells you that $(a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of both $L_z$ and $L^2$ with quantum numbers $m_l=\frac{n}{2}$ and $l=\frac{n}{2}$, or just

$$\left|n,0\right\rangle \propto (a^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle \propto \left|\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right\rangle_l,$$

up to some normalization constant that can be computed using the original state.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understood the idea. But if you be so kind, I'd like to ask the last question (to clarify my understanding). 

Since the total number of quanta $N$ is conserved ( $N = N_a + N_b$ in your notation), then we could treat an arbitrary state as $| k, n \rangle = | k, N - k \rangle$.

As soon as we fixed Hilbert subspace with $N$ quanta, we can enumerate our basis as $|0, N \rangle,  | 1, N-1 \rangle, ... , |N, 0 \rangle, $ and in terms of angular momentum operators, these basis vectors will correspond to $|-l, N+l \rangle, |-l+1, N+l-1 \rangle, ... , |l, N+l \rangle,$ ?

Comment: @MightyPower If $N$ is conserved, then $L^2$ is conserved and $l=N/2$ for all the states. So $|0,N\rangle,\ldots, |N,0\rangle$ would correspond to $|N/2,-N/2\rangle_l,|N/2,-N/2+1\rangle_l,\ldots,|N/2,N/2-1\rangle_l, |N/2,N/2\rangle_l$. You can see how there's $N+1$ states in each basis.

Comment: Thank you!

Could you please recommend to me any literature or article where I can find a similar (or the same) procedure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the normalization constant at first. I don't really know about literature on this; this was one of my homework problems in QM in the past, we used Sakurai but I'm not sure Sakurai covers this in particular. The wikipedia page might be helpful too? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map

Comment: Thank you a lot!